# Laravel search logic issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am developing a search module in Laravel 5.1 that searches businesses along with their phone numbers (records).

```
-- TABLES
businesses: id, name, status
records: id, business_id, number, note
```

The search must return results when both business name AND records note are found for a given keywords. Currently it returns all the businesses even if the associated records(note) does not match.

Here is the code:-

```
$keywords = explode(" ", Request::get('keywords'));
$businesses = App\Business;

$businesses = $businesses->where(function ($query) use ($keywords) {
    foreach ($keywords as $name) {
        $query->orWhere('name', 'like', "$name%");
    }
});

$businesses = $businesses->with(['records' => function ($query) use ($keywords) {
    $query->where('note', 'like', '%'.$keywords[0].'%');

    foreach ($keywords as $note) {
        $query->orWhere('note', 'like', "%$note%");
    }
}]);

$businesses = $businesses->where('status', 1);
$businesses = $businesses->paginate($limit);

return $businesses;
```

Comment: Can you write what you're trying to do in straight SQL? Sometimes that helps me break down complex business logic like this.

Comment: @tptcat, no idea how to write in SQL. The query is simply to find keywords on businesses->name AND records->note. But the above code logic returns all businesses even if their are no match found in records->note.

Comment: Why not use this package and save some time. https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable

Answer (score 0):

Don't explode the keywords because they are separated by space as mentioned. Try the following.

```
$businesses = $businesses->with(['records' => function ($query) use ($keywords) {
            $query->where('note', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%');
        }])->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keywords.'%')->get();
```